# Prevent Car from sliding in Pygame Driving Game

Tags: python, pygame

I'm developing a driving simulator using Python and Pygame. However, I am having some trouble with the handling of the car. Whenever I turn, the car seems to drift like it is on ice or a wet road. Is there any easy way of preventing this from happening?

**Extract from the code:**

```
class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, game, x, y):
    self.groups = game.all_sprites
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    self.game = game
    self.image = game.player_img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.hit_rect = PLAYER_HIT_RECT
    self.hit_rect.center = self.rect.center
    self.vel = vec(0,0)
    self.acc = vec(0,0)
    self.pos = vec(x, y) * TILESIZE
    self.rot = 0

def get_keys(self): #Where all the keypresses are detected and assigned to a feature e.g. movement.
    self.rot_speed = 0
    self.acc = vec(0, 0)
    keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pg.K_w]:
        self.acc = vec(PLAYER_SPEED, 0).rotate(-self.rot)
    if keys[pg.K_a]: # This part of the code is used to reverse the functions of the A and D key, so when you want to reverse, they actually rotate the sprite in the correct direction.
        self.rot_speed = PLAYER_ROT_SPEED
    if keys[pg.K_d]:
        self.rot_speed = -PLAYER_ROT_SPEED
    if keys[pg.K_s]:
        self.acc = vec(-PLAYER_SPEED /5, 0).rotate(-self.rot)
    self.acc += self.vel * PLAYER_FRICTION
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos += self.vel+ 0.02 * self.acc
    self.rect.center = self.pos
```

Thanks for helping!
(some of the annotation isn't correct as its from an older build of the game)

Comment: where are you changing the `self.vel` direction based on the `self.rot_speed`?

Comment: @cmd Isn't he changing acceleration with `self.acc = vec(PLAYER_SPEED, 0).rotate(-self.rot)`, and then velocity based on that with `self.vel += self.acc`? Shouldn't that affect the velocity's direction?

Comment: @RandomDavis yes, but that would act like a space ship. Cars actually change the velocity when the car changes direction(not counting skidding), not only the acceleration.

Comment: @cmd Right, of course. That makes sense. So, the issue here is that he's applying a force in a given direction, but not actually pointing the car's velocity in the new direction, so turning the wheels is acting more like a gentle nudge?

Comment: Can you possibly give me some pointers as to where to change this?